How to make a graph for average adjusted predictions at the mean using the svyglm
I am trying to figure out what is the most accurate way to plot average adjusted predictions at the mean using the svyglm function from the survey package. I have used two approaches so far. One using the ggeffects package and another using predict. Here is a sample dataframe:

# Clear global environment
rm(list=ls()) 

# Load necessary packages
library(survey)
library(dplyr)

# Create a sample data frame with a weight variable
set.seed(123)
# Create a sample data frame
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  mentalhealth_1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),  # continuous outcome variable
  age_rs = runif(100, 18, 80),  # rescaled age variable
  female = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Male", "Female")),  # binary gender as factor
  lessthanhs = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  hsgrad = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  somecollege = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  income_by_20_rs = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled income variable
  un_or_underemployed = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Employed", "Un/Underemployed")),  # employment status as factor
  physical_health_poor = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous physical health variable
  all_religion1 = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous religious status variable
  racial_consciousness = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled racial consciousness
  number_discrim_areas_rs = runif(100, 0, 5),  # number of discrimination areas (rescaled)
  weights = runif(100, 0.5, 2)  # weight variable ranging between 0.5 and 2
)
# Create survey design object with weights
df_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df, weights = ~weights)

# Fit the model using svyglm, which accounts for survey weights
m1 <- svyglm(mentalhealth_1 ~ age_rs + female + lessthanhs + hsgrad + somecollege + 
               income_by_20_rs + un_or_underemployed + physical_health_poor + 
               all_religion1 + racial_consciousness + number_discrim_areas_rs, 
             df_design)

# View the summary of the model
summary(m1)

To make a predictions graph for physical_health_poor using ggeffects I do the following:
# Approach 1: 
preds1 <- predict_response(m1, terms = "physical_health_poor")

preds1

# physical_health_poor | Predicted |       95% CI
# -----------------------------------------------
#                0.00 |     47.84 | 42.00, 53.67
#                0.10 |     47.98 | 42.55, 53.40
#                0.20 |     48.12 | 43.04, 53.20
#                0.30 |     48.26 | 43.45, 53.06
#                0.50 |     48.53 | 44.01, 53.05
#                0.60 |     48.67 | 44.15, 53.20
#                0.70 |     48.81 | 44.18, 53.44
#                0.90 |     49.09 | 43.97, 54.21

# Adjusted for:
# *                  age_rs =    48.72
# *                  female =     Male
# *              lessthanhs =       No
# *                  hsgrad =       No
# *             somecollege =       No
# *         income_by_20_rs =     0.49
# *     un_or_underemployed = Employed
# *           all_religion1 =     0.47
# *    racial_consciousness =     0.49
# * number_discrim_areas_rs =     2.48

# Plot the Results
plot1 <- ggplot(preds1, aes(x = x, y = predicted)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.3) + 
  labs(x = "Physical Health Poor", 
       y = "Wave I Mental Health Poor") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme()

Alternatively, I can use predict
# Using predict
new_data = data.frame(
  age_rs = svymean(~age_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1],
  female = "Male", 
  lessthanhs = "No", 
  hsgrad = "No",
  somecollege = "No", 
  income_by_20_rs = svymean(~income_by_20_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1], 
  un_or_underemployed = "Employed", 
  physical_health_poor = seq(0, 1, length.out = 10),
  all_religion1 = svymean(~all_religion1, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1], 
  racial_consciousness = svymean(~racial_consciousness, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1],
  number_discrim_areas_rs = svymean(~number_discrim_areas_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1]
)


preds_weighted <- as.data.frame(predict(m1, newdata = new_data, se.fit = TRUE, type = "response"))
preds_weighted

plot_data <- data.frame(
  predicted = preds_weighted$response, 
  lower = preds_weighted$response - 1.96 * preds_weighted$SE, 
  upper = preds_weighted$response + 1.96 * preds_weighted$SE
)

head(plot_data,10)

# predicted    lower    upper
# 1   47.83798 42.08503 53.59092
# 2   47.99258 42.68098 53.30417
# 3   48.14718 43.20350 53.09087
# 4   48.30178 43.63517 52.96840
# 5   48.45639 43.95918 52.95359
# 6    48.61099 44.16321 53.05876
# 7   48.76559 44.24333 53.28785
# 8   48.92019 44.20540 53.63498
# 9   49.07479 44.06301 54.08658
# 10  49.22940 43.83338 54.62541

If these two approaches produce different CIs, which is more appropriate for plotting data from a svyglm model? Is there a different, more acceptable approach for plotting model output from models produced using svyglm?

The differences are very small, and I think for following reasons:

the values you adjust for: predict_response() doesn't take the survey mean, but the mean value based on the data. So the non-focal terms are held constant at slightly different values, returning slightly different results.

for the confidence intervals, you multiply the SE with 1.96, while predict_responses() uses qt(0.975, df) to get the exact factor.


For the first point, you can use the condition argument and set exact values. Then you'll see that you get identical results.
library(survey)
library(ggeffects)

# Create a sample data frame with a weight variable
set.seed(123)
# Create a sample data frame
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  mentalhealth_1 = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 10),  # continuous outcome variable
  age_rs = runif(100, 18, 80),  # rescaled age variable
  female = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Male", "Female")),  # binary gender as factor
  lessthanhs = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  hsgrad = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  somecollege = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("No", "Yes")),  # binary education variable as factor
  income_by_20_rs = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled income variable
  un_or_underemployed = factor(sample(c(0, 1), 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("Employed", "Un/Underemployed")),  # employment status as factor
  physical_health_poor = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous physical health variable
  all_religion1 = runif(100, 0, 1),  # continuous religious status variable
  racial_consciousness = runif(100, 0, 1),  # rescaled racial consciousness
  number_discrim_areas_rs = runif(100, 0, 5),  # number of discrimination areas (rescaled)
  weights = runif(100, 0.5, 2)  # weight variable ranging between 0.5 and 2
)
# Create survey design object with weights
df_design <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = df, weights = ~weights)

# Fit the model using svyglm, which accounts for survey weights
m1 <- svyglm(mentalhealth_1 ~ age_rs + female + lessthanhs + hsgrad + somecollege + 
               income_by_20_rs + un_or_underemployed + physical_health_poor + 
               all_religion1 + racial_consciousness + number_discrim_areas_rs, 
             df_design)


# Using predict
new_data = data.frame(
  age_rs = svymean(~age_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1],
  female = "Male", 
  lessthanhs = "No", 
  hsgrad = "No",
  somecollege = "No", 
  income_by_20_rs = svymean(~income_by_20_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1], 
  un_or_underemployed = "Employed", 
  physical_health_poor = seq(0, 0.9, length.out = 10),
  all_religion1 = svymean(~all_religion1, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1], 
  racial_consciousness = svymean(~racial_consciousness, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1],
  number_discrim_areas_rs = svymean(~number_discrim_areas_rs, design = df_design, na.rm = TRUE)[1]
)

preds_weighted <- as.data.frame(predict(m1, newdata = new_data, se.fit = TRUE, type = "response"))
plot_data <- data.frame(
  physical_health_poor = new_data$physical_health_poor,
  predicted = preds_weighted$response, 
  lower = preds_weighted$response - qt(0.975, df = 88) * preds_weighted$SE, 
  upper = preds_weighted$response + qt(0.975, df = 88) * preds_weighted$SE
)
plot_data
#>    physical_health_poor predicted    lower    upper
#> 1                   0.0  47.83798 42.00493 53.67102
#> 2                   0.1  47.97712 42.54989 53.40435
#> 3                   0.2  48.11626 43.03593 53.19659
#> 4                   0.3  48.25540 43.45027 53.06054
#> 5                   0.4  48.39454 43.78007 53.00902
#> 6                   0.5  48.53369 44.01461 53.05276
#> 7                   0.6  48.67283 44.14788 53.19778
#> 8                   0.7  48.81197 44.18024 53.44370
#> 9                   0.8  48.95111 44.11839 53.78384
#> 10                  0.9  49.09025 43.97342 54.20709

preds1 <- predict_response(
  m1,
  terms = "physical_health_poor",
  condition = c(
    age_rs = 48.72228,
    income_by_20_rs = 0.4906447,
    all_religion1 = 0.4702408,
    racial_consciousness = 0.4859259,
    number_discrim_areas_rs = 2.478405
  )
)
preds1
#> # Predicted values of mentalhealth_1
#> 
#> physical_health_poor | Predicted |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------------------
#>                 0.00 |     47.84 | 42.00, 53.67
#>                 0.10 |     47.98 | 42.55, 53.40
#>                 0.20 |     48.12 | 43.04, 53.20
#>                 0.30 |     48.26 | 43.45, 53.06
#>                 0.50 |     48.53 | 44.01, 53.05
#>                 0.60 |     48.67 | 44.15, 53.20
#>                 0.70 |     48.81 | 44.18, 53.44
#>                 0.90 |     49.09 | 43.97, 54.21
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> *              female =     Male
#> *          lessthanhs =       No
#> *              hsgrad =       No
#> *         somecollege =       No
#> * un_or_underemployed = Employed
#> 
#> Not all rows are shown in the output. Use `print(..., n = Inf)` to show
#>   all rows.

Created on 2024-10-11 with reprex v2.1.1
Why did I use qt(0.975, df = 88) instead of 1.96 to compute the confidence intervals? The intervals are based on estimate +/- crit_value * standard_error. The critical value for the test statistic is based on the degrees of freedom. For models with z-statistic, df is Inf and the critical value is close to 1.96 (qnorm(0.975) or qt(0.975, df = Inf)). For models with t-statistic, degrees of freedom are usually smaller the the intervals are thus wider. See following example:
m <- lm(mpg ~ as.factor(gear), data = mtcars)
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))

confint(m)[2, ]
#>     2.5 %    97.5 % 
#>  4.697361 12.155972

t_crit <- 1.96
(coef(m)[2] + c(-1, 1) * t_crit * se[2])
#> [1]  4.85277 12.00056

t_crit <- qt(0.975, df = df.residual(m))
(coef(m)[2] + c(-1, 1) * t_crit * se[2])
#> [1]  4.697361 12.155972

Created on 2024-10-11 with reprex v2.1.1
predict_response() extracts the model's / parameters' degrees of freedom and uses them to calculate the intervals of the predicted values. Thus, if you want to replicate those results using predict(), you have to do the same.

Thank you!  As a follow up, why do you specify df = 88 in qt() section of the code?

See my edits, I gave some explanation at the bottom of my answer.
